# Is it possible to include multiple custom js files for Jupyter notebook?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I know I can add custom javascript to Jupyer notebooks by adding them to:

`.jupyter/custom/custom.js`

However, is there a way to have multiple javascript files that are all loaded, e.g.

`.jupyter/custom/custom1.js`

`.jupyter/custom/custom2.js`

(As I have several Jupyter notebook related related projects going on, having the ability to seperate out custom javascript into multiple files would be helpful).

Answer (score 0):

I usually bundle JavaScript as `.js` files in the same directory as my notebook, and simply load them in the first cell using `IPython.display.HTML(...)`.